# Pinch To Zoom On Camera surface view

Tags: android, camera, zooming, surfaceview

I am creating an android camera application. I want to add pinch to zoom feature on the Surface View of the application. I have found many codes but they all were for scaling the imageview. If there is no code for it then can i implement the zoom for imageview code to the surfaceview?

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work. Preview surface view cannot be zoomed beyond the screen size. But using SurfaceTexture does not have such limitations. Zoom in OpenGl is very efficient and easy.